# Create Sharepoint connector to apply Digital Signature using Smartcards or USB Tokens?

Tags: sharepoint, digital-signature, smartcard, pki

Is there a document or guide for how to use smartcard or USB Tokens in signing documents and approvals?

> We have in our company a Sharepoint 2013 server, and our employees have their own smartcards which are used in windows Domain login.

I found some connectors like Docusign and Signing Hub connectors that allow digital signing using smartcard and USB Tokens. However, we want to create our own tool by our Sharepoint developers. Is there a document or guide for how to apply this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a member of the DocuSign team. Note that our SharePoint Connector enables you to apply standard digital signatures on documents and list items residing in SharePoint, as well as integrate the signature operations with SharePoint and Nintex workflows. These digital signatures operations are powered by a centralized (and secure) Signature Appliance.

If you are considering building your own connector that implements digital signatures in a client-held token (such as a smartcard or USB token), apart for the obvious SharePoint-side functionality and customizations (menus, signature objects, views, etc.) you will also need to implement a browser-component (Active X for IE, Native Messaging for Chrome and Firefox, etc.) to communicate between the Web Application and browser with the native signature hardware token on the client side.

Comment: Thanks Ari for your answer.
Can you provide me with any description for your mentioned appliance, i want to know how does the process flow?

Comment: Sure. The following link can provide more info:
https://www.docusign.com/partner/sharepoint-server-for-cosign-central

Please feel free to contact me on my corporate e-mail if you find this interesting: ari.seror@docusign.com

Comment: Thanks Ari. May be soon if Allah wills.